# How to add custom button to Case Feed

Tags: custom-button, page-layout, casefeed

I want to add custom button to Case Feed as shown below.

[image]

On click of this button, I want to show a popup(visualforce page) with translated email content.

Basically Agent should be able to see email content in his own language.

Any help or solution for this?

Comment: Are you trying to add custom button to email feed on case?If yes i don’t think salesforce provides a way to add it.

Comment: Yes, I want to add custom button to email feed.